# How to setup Angular Material Chip Contol with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular Reactive Form with Angular Materials

For all my controls I add the required validator.

I'm not sure how to setup the chips control correctly with reactive forms.

Where do you set the formControlName so that the required validator fires? At the moment I have it set on the input field which I'm guessing is wrong.

I just want the courseIds to be a comma seperated string with the course ids.

TS:

```
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      courseIds: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let cid of courseIds" (removed) = "...">
          {{cid}}
        </mat-chip>

        <input matInput formControlName="courseIds"
               [matChipInputFor]="chipList" 
               placeholder="Ids" 
               (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
      </mat-chip-list>
   </mat-form-field>    

....

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Chips aren't form components by themselves : they just display a value with a given style. To sum it up, you would like to have your chips display the value of the input, which is a string with commas in it ?

Comment: [Something like this ?](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-favnft?file=app/chips-overview-example.html)

Comment: No, I have that all working fine. I need the chip control to fail validation (required) if no chips are selected. So where do I set the formControlName?

Comment: oh okay, then please see the blitz again, tell me if it suits you !

Answer (score 43):

Try setting the `formControlName` at the `<mat-chip-list>` level.

In your template, set the `ngFor` to loop over the `courseIds` control value

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-chip-list #chipList formControlName="courseIds">
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let cid of form.get('courseIds').value" (removed) = "...">
            {{cid}}
        </mat-chip>

        <input matInput
            [matChipInputFor]="chipList" 
            placeholder="Ids" 
            (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
    </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then in your component, create the form group with the initial values for `courseIds` if any, else use an empty array `[]` (since the chips display an array and not a string). In your `add()` and `remove()` function, add and remove the values from the `courseIds` control value respectively.

```js
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
        courseIds: new FormControl([], Validators.required)
    });
}

add() {
    ...

    // Add new input to courseIds control value
    this.courseIds.value.push(value);

    this.courseIds.updateValueAndValidity();
}

remove() {
    ...

    // Remove element from control value array
    this.courseIds.value.splice(index, 1);    // where index = index of removed element

    this.courseIds.updateValueAndValidity();
}

// use getter method to access courseIds control value easily
get courseIds() { 
    return this.form.get('courseIds');
}
```

Comment: beat me to it, here's a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gjwo4

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but note that the stackblitz example by @than is better, since it doesn't have the `formControlName` attribute on the `input` element.

Having that attribute there, causes errors when typing into the input because the chips are being rendered by iterating over the `FormControl` value

Comment: @Nexaddo -  Thanks for pointing that out. I typed my answer so I must've missed that. There were 2 `formControlName`s in my code. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @than, you're legend!

Comment: For anyone that needs another reference, here is my version. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gjwo4-pyjmrj?file=app/chips-input-example.ts

Answer (score 8):

When combining FormArrays with nash11 his answer it won't work. I had the problem that when i edit another formArray in the same form group the changes in the mat-chip list where lost.

Therefore here is my solution how to use material chip control with reactive forms + forms array.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gjwo4-h4f9ux?file=app/chips-input-example.ts

chips-input-example.html:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
        <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection" formArrayName="fruits">
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruitControls.value" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
                (removed)="remove(fruit)">
                {{fruit}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
            <input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

chips-input-example.ts

```js
import { COMMA, ENTER } from "@angular/cdk/keycodes";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MatChipInputEvent } from "@angular/material/chips";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupDirective,
  NgForm,
  Validators,
  FormBuilder,
  FormArray
} from "@angular/forms";

/**
 * @title Chips with input
 */
@Component({
  selector: "chips-input-example",
  templateUrl: "chips-input-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["chips-input-example.css"]
})
export class ChipsInputExample {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      fruits: this.fb.array(["Lemon", "Lime", "Apple"], Validators.required)
    });
  }

  get fruitControls(): FormArray {
    return this.form.controls.fruits as FormArray;
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || "").trim()) {
      this.fruitControls.push(this.fb.control(value));
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = "";
    }
  }

  remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.fruitControls.value.indexOf(fruit);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruitControls.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
}
```